# Manually verify certificates in Python3 ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, certificate

I am developing the client- and server-side of a Python3 application. They must communicate over TLS using self-signed certs.

The connection should always be established, even if both have never seen the other, thus neither has the other's cert in its trust store. Verification shall happen after the handshake with a custom method.

However, Python's [ssl library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.check_hostname) attempts to verify the certificate during handshake and this fails if the incoming cert is unknown and has no valid certificate chain. Setting `verify_mode` to `CERT_NONE` is also not an option, since I do require the certificates from both sides for my custom verification method.

So my question: How can I require a certificate from the other side but turn off automatic verification during handshake? Or maybe I can pass a custom verifyer-method that gets called?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should consider creating one root selfsigned certificate, adding it in trust store and then signing client and server certificates with it?

Comment: Interesting Idea, thanks. That would probably work. And since there is still the "real" verification happening after the handshake, this self-signed root cert would not have to be handled with care but could be shipped with the software.

It does not seem to be a very elegant solution, though. I would still prefer simply to turn off the automatic verification attempt.

Comment: If you don't use certificate validation at all, your service will become vulnerable to MiTM attacks, so I advice you not to turn it off and ship software with private root key inside it.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I am well aware of that and I do plan to verify endpoint identity. I simply want to do it in a custom way.

Comment: I have the same need. I want to use Python to check some certificates expiration date. The certificate may be auto-signed or signed by an a untrusted authority but I need to get it to get the details, to know when it’s going to expire.
I did it in a shell script using curl with the --verbose option, I thought I would do it in a couple of minute using requests but it is not as easy, even using urllib3 or socket directly…

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ssl.get_server_certificate((host,port))`. It will return the certificate in PEM format.